# how this query is working.....can anyone explain

Tags: sql

```
SELECT productid,productname,price
FROM products E1 
WHERE 4 = (SELECT count(*) 
           FROM products E2 
           WHERE E1.price =E2.price)
```

Comment: Look for `Correlated subquery`

Answer (score 1):

It's working like this

```
SELECT productid,productname,price
FROM products E1 
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM products E2 WHERE E1.price =E2.price) = 4
```

:) Now does it make more sense?

Although it can be simplified

```
SELECT productid,productname,price,COUNT(*) AS c
FROM products
GROUP BY PRICE
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

Comment: ANSI SQL requires HAVING COUNT(*)  = 4, i.e. no column alias in HAVING clause. (Or in where, or in group by....)

Answer (score 0):

The outer query ill scan all products.

For each product the subquery ill count how many products got the same price.

The filter (where clause) ill avoid subquery counts different from four.

The output ill be all products where there are four products with same price.

If anyone is using MS-SQL the same thing can be done using aggregates (count and having)

**Edit** Hanky already posted the MS-SQL equivalent query using count and having